# Using JPA Annotations and Map<String,String> with a varchar length

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got an entity that contains the following member attributes:

```
@Id
protected String id;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@MapKeyClass(String.class)      
protected Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

This maps to two tables, an ENTITY table, and an ENTITY_DATA table which contains a row for each element in the HashMap.  It maps the values in the HashMap as VARCHAR(256) and I need it to be VARCHAR(1024).  Can this be done? I cannot find anything in the ElementCollection or MapKeyClass annotations that would allow for this.

Comment: As a side note - you **don't need to** specify the `targetClass` nor the `@MapKeyClass` if you use generics. These types can be inferred from Java types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, as you say, problem is with values, it goes as with columns in general. Just add following annotation to the field.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(1024)")
```

With JPA 2.0 you can do same also to field where key of the map is persisted with [MapKeyColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyColumn.html) annotation:

```
@MapKeyColumn(columnDefinition = "varchar(1024)")
```